# When running Docker: Cannot connect to SQL Server Browser. Ensure SQL Server Browser has been started

Tags: sql-server, docker, asp.net-core, networking, deployment

I am trying to deploy my REST API .NET Core app with Docker for the first time, however, after creating my docker image, when I try to run:

`docker run -p 8080:80 mydockerid/dockerapi`

I get a big call stack among which there's the error:

```
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[20004]
      An error occurred using the connection to database 'CommanderDB' on server 'HELLO\SQLEXPRESS'.
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[10100]
      An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'Commander.Data.CommanderContext'.
      System.Exception: Cannot connect to SQL Server Browser. Ensure SQL Server Browser has been started.
       ---> System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException (00000005, 0xFFFDFFFF): Name or service not known
         at System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByName(String hostName)
         at System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(String hostNameOrAddress)
         at System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient.BeginSend(Byte[] datagram, Int32 bytes, String hostname, Int32 port, AsyncCallback requestCallback, Object state)
         at System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient.<>c.<SendAsync>b__56_0(Tuple`2 targetPackedArguments, Int32 targetBytes, Int32 targetPort, AsyncCallback callback, Object 
state)
```

After some research, I think the problem might be the 'Server Name' of my SQL Server Express. When I login on SQL Server Management Studio, I use 'HELLO\SQLEXPRESS' as the server name:

[image]

Here is my connection string in appsettings.json:

`"CommanderConnection": "Server=HELLO\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=CommanderAPI;User ID=myid;Password=mypassword;"`

Should my server name be something else? Perhaps there's a way to change the server name to an actual IP address?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The SQL Browser service listens on udp/1434, which means extra dancing with firewalls and port mapping. If you know the tcp port that your SQL Server instance is listening on then just avoid SQL Browser service altogether and connect to `tcp:server_ip,server_port`, e.g.: `tcp:127.0.0.1,1433`.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Thanks for replying. Do you mean having ```127.0.0.1,1433``` as my server name for SQL Server? I just tried that but I cannot connect to my db with this server name. I checked in configuration to see what my server port is; the case was blank so I put in there 1433 myself, and enabled TCP/IP connection however, this did not solve the problem.

Comment: If you change the protocol configuration you need to restart the SQL Server service for the changes to take effect (or in this case, restart the docker container).

Answer (score 1):

By default SQLEXPRESS do not accept remote connections. Follow this manual to configure TCP/IP connections.

http://support.webecs.com/kb/a868/how-do-i-configure-sql-server-express-to-allow-remote-tcp-ip-connections-on-port-1433.aspx

Then try connect to your database using hostname and port. First try locally and then you can configure your app same way.

For sake of experiment you can also start SQLEXPRESS as docker container. Check this manual - https://kimsereyblog.blogspot.com/2018/10/docker-compose-asp-net-core-application.html

Comment: I tried the first thing you proposed, however I was unable to connect to my db. When you say connect to my db using hostname and port, what would be the hostname? Is it the 127.0.0.1? I am thinking of simply also making my sql db a container then connecting the two.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 will definetely not work as host name, because this will be recognised as container internal address. Can you call your hosting computer with some recognised DNS name? Also you can try find out your hosting machine IP address (check with ipconfig command) and use it for connection.

For making your SQL db as a container use second link I sent. Use docker-compose command to configure both deployments.